# Dynamically fetching json files in vite react?

Tags: reactjs, json, vite

I have been trying to fetch data in the form of json files dynamically but I am getting some strange results. The jsons is unable to be fetched (i.e., returns an error that's caught by catch()) on page load but work after refreshing vite in my code editor by saving or editing the page contents. The jsons are stored in `/public/condition_data/` and when I go to `127.0.0.1:5173/condition_data/file.json` in my browser, it appears to load the json successfully.

I've tried using fs.filepath and dynamic imports but it did not work.

Here is the code snippet:

```
    const [conditionData, setConditionData] = useState<JSON>();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/condition_data/${condition}.json`)
            .then((res: Response) => res.json())
            .then((data: JSON) => setConditionData(data))
            .then(() => console.log(conditionData))
            .catch(() => console.log('error'));
    }, [])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "the jsons appear to fail" mean in practice?

Comment: That `useEffect` would need to have `condition` as a dependency, by the way. You might also want to consider e.g. [`swr`](https://swr.vercel.app/) instead of rolling that logic by yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by vite react? Just the setup that react uses vite? I don't see how vite would be relevant

Comment: can you log the actual error instead of the string 'error'? also, setState is asynchronous, logging state right after setting it might not work as you expected

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused after you created a json file in your backend. Try to debug in your backend even you can log on console.
I mean that creating Json file was succeed but after that you have some errors in your backend side.
Thank you.

Comment: The json files aren't created by the backend. They're just static files that I use to store data.

Comment: Could you provide me a detailed code? Provided code only shows the getting method.